How to customize the well-known endpoint in Spring Authorization Server?
I'm using Spring Authorization Server v3.3.1. My current well-known endpoint is <hostname>/.well-known/openid-configuration and this returns the standard OpenId configuration.
I want to remove a couple of attributes from this standard response and change the endpoint path to <hostname>/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration.
For this I've duplicated the OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter and made the necessary changes and registered it to the authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain.
Request Matcher in the duplicated filter is as follows:
private static RequestMatcher createRequestMatcher() {
    final RequestMatcher defaultRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(
        "/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration", HttpMethod.GET.name());
    return (request) -> defaultRequestMatcher.matches(request);
    }

This is how I've added the filter to the chain:
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .authorizationEndpoint((authorizationEndpoint) -> authorizationEndpoint
                        .authenticationProviders(configureAuthenticationValidator()))
                .tokenEndpoint((tokenEndpoint) -> tokenEndpoint
                        .authenticationProviders(configureAuthenticationValidator())
                        .errorResponseHandler(new ErrorResponseHandler()))
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        // Duplicated Filter
        OidcWellknownEndpointFilter oidcWellknownEndpointFilter = new OidcWellknownEndpointFilter();
        http.addFilterBefore(oidcWellknownEndpointFilter,
                AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

My question is, how can I direct requests coming to the /oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration to the OidcWellknownEndpointFilter?
I tried to add a permitAll() for this endpoint like below:
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration").permitAll());
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer.... <other code>
    }

This will redirect all the requests coming to the endpoint to the login page.
Appreciate any help regarding this.

The docs cover how to customize the well-known endpoint without providing a custom filter. See OpenID Connect 1.0 Provider Configuration Endpoint.
Configuring paths is explained in Configuring Authorization Server Settings. However, you cannot change the path for well-known endpoints because it would make them "not well-known". The path should remain as-is. You can use an issuer identifier to prefix the path, which the OpenID discovery spec allows.

Thanks. It explains how to customize the response but I couldn't find anything on how to customize the well-known path. Can you please  point me to a doc if I missed it?

Updated. You cannot change the path for a well-known endpoint. That would defeat the purpose of it being well-known.

Noted. Thanks Steve.
